# Cancelling NSJSONSerialization - Search as you type, requests overlapping

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurlconnection, nsjsonserialization

Similar to the iPhone Facebook app search function, I am implementing search as you type functionality into my application although I have a problem when decoding the data into JSON format.

Basically what happens is because some searches take longer than others, they return at different intervals and this causes some small visual issues when the data is presenting on the screen.

I have set an NSLOG after each decode using NSJSONSerialization for the keyword 'industry'

```
2013-04-09 23:38:18.941 Project Name [42836:1d03] http://fooWebAddress/json/?method=search&limit=10&q=indus
2013-04-09 23:38:19.776 Project Name [42836:3e07] http://fooWebAddress/json/?method=search&limit=10&q=indu
2013-04-09 23:38:20.352 Project Name [42836:8803] http://fooWebAddress/json/?method=search&limit=10&q=indust
2013-04-09 23:38:21.814 Project Name [42836:4e03] http://fooWebAddress/json/?method=search&limit=10&q=industr
2013-04-09 23:38:23.434 Project Name [42836:8803] http://fooWebAddress/json/?method=search&limit=10&q=ind
2013-04-09 23:38:24.070 Project Name [42836:7503] http://fooWebAddress/json/?method=search&limit=10&q=industry
```

As you can see it is all out of order.

Does anyone have any way of stopping NSJSONSerialization for the previous connection. 
Or possibly any other way to go about this problem?

---

Steps up to NSJSONSerialization...

1. NSURLRequest (initwithURL)
2. NSOperationQueue
3. NSURLConnection (asynchronous)
4. NSJSONSerialization

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you cancel previous operations (if so, how) ?

Comment: just wait till user stop typing and then only call web-service. In between is user is typing continuously, cancel previous request to call web-service using below code.

    [NSObject cancelPerformSelectorsWithTarget:self];
    [self performSelector:@selector(sendSearchRequest) withObject:searchText afterDelay:0.1f];

Answer (score 1):

When the user starts typing more text, you *could* cancel your previous connections and ignore any further delegate callbacks you receive from them. Then make the new request for the current text.

You can do this by maintaining some sort of `lastRequest` or `lastOperation` reference. When the user starts typing, call `[self.lastRequestOrOperation cancel]` and ignore any further notifications from that request with a check like `if (request != self.lastRequest) { return; }` in whatever callbacks you have.

However this has the problem that if the user keeps typing for a while you are constantly cancelling requests and they may not see any results until they have stopped typing.

A better solution would be to add sequencing so that each request is associated with an increasing sequence ID. You then only parse the result and update the UI  when the sequence of the response is higher than the last one you received. If you receive any out-of-band responses from earlier, you just ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a much more complex issue than just being able to cancel the `NSJSONSerialization`. My suggestion is to use `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate your table view that shows the search results. Use the search term as one of the predicate variable in the `NSFetchRequest` attached to `NSFetchedResultsController`. And then, when you parse the results using `NSJSONSerialization`, store the results with the search term associated with that request. As soon as the search term changed (which you can detect when the user types more characters), re-create the `NSFetchedResultsController` and reload your table view. In addition, you can also try to cancel the call to parse the previous results if you launched it using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay. Beware that this cannot be always relied upon as the call may have been initiated by the time you are trying to cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda basic, but you could always maintain an nsdictionary of sub-classed NSURLRequests (sub-classed to provide a tag).

Start request - add request to dicationary with tag = array.count - 1, with key matching tag
Connection returns - is the request the most recent request, if so, parse json
Parse JSON - is the request the most recent request, if so, show results, if not, only display if there are no previous results displayed
Request handling - remove key from dictionary

most recent request = does the dictionary contain an object with a higher key value

Answer (score 0):

Currently what you are doing is, you type each character and calling web-service. Why to call web-service for each letter you type. If user is type continuously, then it will increase the load, so call the web-service only when user stops for a particular interval of time. and then pass that string to call web-service or what ever method you are calling.

```
[NSObject cancelPerformSelectorsWithTarget:self]; // This will cancel your all req which is going to make when user typing without stopping 
[self performSelector:@selector(sendSearchRequest) withObject:searchText afterDelay:0.1f]; // This will pass the string to call a web-service method, on which user hold for some time.
```